# Combine Static Columns with Dynamic Columns in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table SchoolStudent with three columns and the following values

[image]

Now, for a student we can have dynamic columns which are stored in a table with values as:

[image]

I want a query where i can club static fields as well as dynamic fields in a single SQL Query. I tried using Pivot but was not successful. Please suggest on how to accomplish this. I am basically doing it so that on frontend i have one resultset which can be searched thru.

So query should be:

```
Select 
    StudentID, FirstName, Address, MotherName, 
    MotherEmail, MotherOccupation, Mother Salary, 
    FacebookProfileName, VehicleRegNo 
from SchoolStudent 
Inner Join 
    (Logic to convert rows to columns)
```

Comment: I Suggest you use and integer ID that would represent the type of value stored int the row on the second table instead of DynamicColumnaName because it will help to eliminate redundancy and will improve consistency of data that you are trying to store.

Comment: Yes it is an integer only. The table is a simplification of result of join of two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have dynamic columns, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to generate the result that you want. This query will generate the list of columns in the second table and PIVOT them to then be joined to the `SchoolStudent` to get the other columns:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DynamicColumnName) 
                    from StudentDetails
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
         select s.studentid,
            s.firstname,
            s.address,
            d.*
         from SchoolStudent s
         inner join 
         (
            SELECT studentId,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select studentId, dynamiccolumnname, 
                  dynamiccolumnvalue
                from StudentDetails
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(dynamiccolumnvalue)
                for dynamiccolumnname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
          ) d
            on s.StudentId = d.StudentId'

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ac7a4/2). This query gives the result:

```
| STUDENTID | FIRSTNAME |   ADDRESS | FACEBOOK PROFILE NAME | MOTHER EMAIL | MOTHER NAME | MOTHER OCCUPATION | MOTHER SALARY | VEHICLE REG NO |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         4 |     admin | efewfwfew |                  ross |  ram@ram.com | ram@ram.com |       ram@ram.com |   ram@ram.com |       UP 14 as |
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sub query format like this:

```
SELECT t1.StudentID, 
       t1.FirstName, 
       t1.Address, 
       (SELECT t2.DynamicColumnValue FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.StudentID = t1.StudentID AND t2.DynamicColumnName = 'Mother Name') AS 'MotherName',
       (SELECT t2.DynamicColumnValue FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.StudentID = t1.StudentID AND t2.DynamicColumnName = 'Mother Email') AS 'MotherEmail'
FROM Table1 t1
```

or you could use inner join format like this:

```
SELECT t1.StudentID, 
       t1.FirstName, 
       t1.Address,
       t2.DynamicColumnValue AS 'MotherName'
       t3.DynamicColumnValue AS 'MotherEmail'
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID AND t2.DynamicColumnName = 'Mother Name'
INNER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t1.StudentID = t3.StudentID AND t2.DynamicColumnName = 'Mother Email'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction, however since dynamic columns can be many and it will be dynamic decision so i think i will have to use dynamic queries combined with your solution to list all dynamic columns in select list. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Ahmm I believe you're trying to implement something that is cool. Personally, I just do this kind of stuff when i  need to normalize my information and I'm not quite really familiar with dynamic queries. sorry if i failed to convey what you need ;).. i'll be happy too see elegant solution for your question.

Answer (score 1):

With some dynamic sql, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + DynamicColumnName FROM DynamicValues ORDER BY '],[' + DynamicColumnName FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @query = N'select s.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.Address,'+@cols+' from SchoolStudent s
join
(
    select * from DynamicValues
    pivot (Max(DynamicColumnValue) for DynamicColumnName in ('+@cols+')) as pvt
) as b on b.StudentID=s.StudentID'
EXECUTE(@query)
```